# Cell color changes based on conditions in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement to have a tracker in Excel in which color changes based on Condition. Cell D has Due Date & E:H also has date. When the E:H columns date changes the color also changes based on conditions. Please Help. Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = ""
     Else
        'Dim oldVal As Date
        Set oldVal = Oval
        'MsgBox oldVal
         Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
         Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
         Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = Date
         Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = Date
    End If
End If
Call ColorMeElmo
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = ""
     Else
        'Dim oldVal As Date
        Set oldVal = Oval
        'MsgBox oldVal
         Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
         Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
         Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = Date
         Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = Date
    End If
End If
Call ColorMeElmo
End Sub


Sub ColorMeElmo()
   MsgBox "Called Coror"
   Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

   For i = 2 To 5
      Set r1 = Range("D" & i)
      Set r2 = Range("E" & i & ":H" & i)
     
      Dim diff As Long
      diff = DateDiff("D", r1.Value, r2.Value)
      
      If diff > 10 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
      If diff < 11 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
      
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with the code you posted?

Comment: Is having the exact same procedure twice in  your code just a mistake in the question?  `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` appears twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateDiff formula need two date values, but r2.value is not a valid date.
change:

```
Set r2 = Range("E" & i & ":H" & i)
```

to:

```
Set r2 = Range("E" & i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more question. I need to change Cell "E" to "H" with color based on "E:H" values with Cell "D". Example: Suppose "D2" cell has 06/30/2022 and "E2" Cell 06/10/2022, "F2" cell has 06/15/2022. So "E" and "F" cells color will change according to the calculation. Thanks

Comment: you can repeat the for loop 3 times, and replace "E" with "F", "G" and "H".

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do we have any other option instead of manually writing the Cell Name index like "E", "F" etc